# Controller doesn't recognize database/table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have my controller with a `Public ActionResult BestuuurEdit` and I want to apply code from a YouTube tutorial into my code. The code:

```
public ActionResult BestuuurEdit(int id)
    {
        Persoon persoon = db.Persoon.Find(id);
        if(persoon == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(persoon);
    }
```

But when applying the code I get the following errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Persoon' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The name 'db' does not exist in the current context.

My full controller:

```
using OrgPlanTool.BestuurService;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OrgPlanTool.Models.Bestuuur;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;

namespace OrgPlanTool.Controllers
{

public class BestuuurController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult BestuuurView()
    {

        BestuurService.BestuurServiceClient client = new BestuurService.BestuurServiceClient();

        //  BestuuurModel model = new BestuuurModel();
        //model.bestuur = client.GetBestuurByNaam(2);
         BestuurModel2 model = new BestuurModel2(client.GetBestuurByOrganisatieId(17));
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult BestuuurEdit(int id)
    {
        Persoon persoon = db.Persoon.Find(id);
        if(persoon == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(persoon);
        //BestuurService.BestuurServiceClient client = new BestuurService.BestuurServiceClient();
        //BestuurModel2 model = new BestuurModel2(client.GetBestuurByOrganisatieId(17));


        //return View(model);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where you created db object ...?

Comment: Nowhere, I can't use my `public PlanToolEntities db = new PlanToolEntities();` for some reason.

Comment: Where are you creating person or db object?  Look under models you might have created it there. If you can't use a model/db variable means you have not created it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write constructor method like this in order to create your db

```
public class BestuuurController : Controller
{    
    BestuuurController(PlanToolEntities context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    PlanToolEntities db;
}
```

Comment: Where should I place that? Because when I replace `Bestuuurcontroller : Controller` with that I get errors

Comment: in your Bestuuurcontroller class

Comment: It's giving me this error now:
"The type or namespace name 'PlanToolEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: what is the name of your DbContext? replace it with 'PlanToolEntities'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112128/discussion-between-arvin-and-lucafraser).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your db context to the controller. In a simple tutorial it is probably something like this:

```
public class BestuuurController : Controller
{ 
   private PlanToolEntities db = new PlanToolEntities(); \\ <- at minimum this should be added
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be some thing like this

```
public ActionResult BestuuurEdit(int id)
    {
                using (var db = new PlanToolEntities())
                {
                    Persoon persoon = db.Persoon.Find(id);
                        if(persoon == null)
                        {
                            return HttpNotFound();
                        }
                        return View(persoon);
                }
}
```